# Add wrapper on date columns in SQL server

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-server-2012, timezone

I have DB with tables having datetime columns.

Can I add wrapper over those dateTime columns which I can activate/deactivate as per my need, so that all date time converted to a specific Timezone before retrieval.

e.g. I have a Table **ABC** with column **ExpDate** having value **'12-10-2019 2:30'**

When I execute 
`select * from ExpDate`
then it will result
**'12-09-2019 19:30'** (after converting it from UTC to PST(UTC-7))

I want this solution be generic so that it get implemented for all dataTime column in all tables.

Comment: what database do you use? MSSql, or Oracle? plsql belongs to Oracle and not to mssql

Comment: I need it for sqlserver & postgresql

Comment: Define your column as "ExpDate timestamp with time zone". This causes the values to be stored in UTC. Also set your postgresql.conf file timezone entry to your desired timezone. Postgres will automatically convert UTC to server time. Check the table pg_timezone_names for the exact value you want, I guess "US/Pacific", I would not recommend "PST" as it doesn't adjust for daylight savings - at least I don't think it does,never actually used it.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention. Above for Postgres only, don't know about MS Sql Server.